# How to test that my cakePHP installation is working?

Tags: php, cakephp

My application path looks like this: home/webadmin/problemio.com/html

In fact, I output it here on the test url: http://www.problemio.com

I installed CakePHP into the /problemio.com directory, but should it live one down at the root of the application, in the /html directory?

Thanks!

Also, I just moved the cakephp install to the root dir, and I got all these errors there:

Here is how it looks like: http://www.problemio.com/cakephp/

Btw, should I just rename that dir as my application name, and put my index.php in that dir instead of the root?

Comment: Installation of CakePHP is covered in the official docs: http://book.cakephp.org/view/912/Installation

Answer (score 1):

Your webroot should be set to `/home/webadmin/problemio.com/html/cakephp/app/webroot`

Your app basically is in the `/home/webadmin/problemio.com/html/cakephp/app/` (you modify files only in this directory and subdirecetories)

`/home/webadmin/problemio.com/html/cakephp/cake` is where cakephp framework code lives and you should not alter any code there as it's 3rd party code.

Read more about folder structure [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/899/CakePHP-Folder-Structure).

Answer (score 1):

you have set up cake correctly, the errors [here](http://www.problemio.com/cakephp/) are not errors, just warnings. To get rid of them do the following.

1) set recursively cakephp/app/temp permissions to 775 or 777
2) go to cakephp/app/config/core.php and change security salt and security cipher seed.
3) go to cakephp/app/config and create database.php (you have a model there) and configure your database.
4) the last error, you have to reinstall the pcre... (sometimes you won't be able to do it but it may not affect you)

i suggest you follow Janis Veinbergs answer for a correct setting of the folders. The actual configuration works... just some warnings